# iOS Pinch gesture recognizer tolerance

Tags: ios, properties, gestures, pinch

all.

Is there a way to increase the timing tolerance for the pinch gesture?  By default your fingers have to touch down *EXACTLY* at the same time or another gesture gets the touches (scroll or longpress usually).  I'd like to increase the tolerance to maybe half a second, but didn't see any properties for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these flags: delaysTouchesBegan, delaysTouchesEnded

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Those appear to delay sending touch events to the "regular" onTouchesBegan/etc. delegates of the UIView.  I don't have any code in those functions because gestures are supposed to do it all (according to Apple's API docs).  My touch processing is almost all in the UILongPressRecognizer handler.  Are you saying those properties work in some other way?

Comment: Forgot to post last week but I tried those and they made no difference whatsoever in the pinch behavior.